# Integrate GA or GA360 with SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, google-analytics

Does anyone know if the free version of Google Analytics (GA) can be integrated with Salesforce Marketing Cloud or do we have to purchase Google Analytics 360 ?

Comment: What integration scope do you have in mind?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you are trying to achieve with a Google Analytic integration? Is it for getting Salesforce data into Google Analytic, or for customer re-targeting? These are the 2 most common use cases.

Comment: The client doesn't want to use the paid version and they just want basic tracking analytics on their website from SFMC email sends at the email & subscriber level. Based on the comments by zuzannamj below I think that's what I'm looking for but open to other comments.@Cameron Robert

Answer (score 9):

Sorry, it will only work with the paid version - already had a few clients ask about this.

If you look at [Salesforce resources](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/google-analytics-360-integration-for-marketing-cloud/get-started-with-the-analytics-360-integration-for-marketing-cloud), you will see that it says:

> You must be a Salesforce Marketing Cloud customer with
>   Journey Builder enabled in your account and be a Google Analytics 360
>   customer.

And now the resources from Google Analytics:

[image]

To be able to use the main feature of this integration, which lets you use GA360 audiences as entry source in Journey Builder, you will need the paid version.

If you however only want to track (in GA) the traffic coming to your website from SFMC emails, including tracking at subscriber, email and campaign level, you can use a free feature called Web Analytics Connector. Read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_wa_web_analytics_connector.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it! I believe that's exactly what we are looking for. @zuzannamj

Comment: Glad I could help @Girish - please remember to mark the answer as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

There is also a paid for service, a managed package to install in Salesforce (not yet an AppExchange partner though...) called GAConnector which I have used with a couple of clients now (with Pardot & Salesforce).

It surprasses the level of details on all out-of-the-box connectors without the Google Analytics 360 price tag and is relatively easy to configure (no need for Dev help/only admin changes). You can add up to 20+ Google Analytics (including Google Ads info) on any Salesforce Objects (especially Leads/Opportunities/Contacts/Accounts) and send Salesforce objects conversion information to your Google Analytics view to enhance your reports.

The Google 360 pricing does not make complete sense as almost every single online business uses marketing campaigns and thus needs to know and analyse ROI and attribution to the best of their ability! Now for big enterprise clients they could use GAConnector as a proof of concept to build a business case to purchase Google 360...

https://gaconnector.com/blog/salesforce-and-google-analytics-integration/

May 2022 Update: Following the announcement that Google Analytics is going to sunsetted in favour of G4 in Summer 2023, this integration can only be sustainable if GAConnector start offering a new product equivalent i.e "G4 Connector" going forward...

Comment: Thanks @Delphine T!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like things have been upgraded.

The [google analytics integration](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_gai_google_analytics_integration_tracking.htm&type=5) for SFMC lets you track and analyze journey activity through your Google Analytics account without assistance from technical support or services.
You determine the URL tags and how data is collected and presented in the customizable Google Analytics reporting dashboard.

Now you can use Google’s native authentication to securely link your Marketing Cloud and Google Analytics 360 or Google Analytics Free accounts.

The difference is that Google Analytics Free users get access to sampled data reporting about their customer interactions. Marketing Cloud adheres to Google’s [sampling rate](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).

Google Analytics 360 users get access to unsampled data and audiences, empowering them to act on the reporting that Google and Salesforce provide. Google Analytics 360 customers can market to customers in your audiences in Journey Builder using the Google Analytics 360 entry source.