# Integrate GA or GA360 with SFMC : What can we do with GA integration on SFMC other than UTM tag?

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, google-analytics

When we integrated SFMC with GA(FREE), what kind of report is available on SFMC?

Is this(the image below) referring the reporting dashboard in each Email Activity ?
Or is there other one ?
I read some articles here, and learned that we won't be able to collect conversion/revenue from Data View or backend on SFMC. ([Integrate GA or GA360 with SFMC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/281483/integrate-ga-or-ga360-with-sfmc))

[image]

If anyone can clarify, weather we can create customized/out of box report using GA data on SFMC, it would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do reporting based on GA data in SFMC. However, you will be able to access selected metrics from GA in the Journey Analytics tab of your journey, as a dashboard. These will be metrics attributed to activities within this particular journey. Below is an example screenshot from a GA 360 enabled account, but to my knowledge the standard GA does not differ much from GA360 from a UI perspective. The major difference is on the underlying data.
While GA360 uses unsampled data, you will see a higher precision in the metrics delivered, compared to the standard GA edition.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Lucas, thank you for claying. This is very helpful.